# How do I define an array/collection of all the values within a certain category in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

So I have a spreadsheet, with a bunch of names in B51:B220, a few groups in H9;H35, and the corresponding group each name belongs to, in H51:H220. Some of the names in column B are filled red based on a macro I still can’t believe I successfully wrote all by myself.

I’m not sure what exactly I’m doing, but what I’m *trying* to do is create a count of all the red names in a certain group, and then list that count next to the corresponding group up in the key, in cells F9:F35.

I’m continuing to work on this code even while it’s up here, and editing my post as I progress further.

I know I’m still far from useable code, but here’s what I have so far, other than hopes and dreams:

```
Sub Team()

Dim TL as Range
Dim GLA as Collection
Dim LA as Variant 
Dim p as Integer 
Dim t as Integer 
p = 0 

‘p is the number of red names 
‘t is the row number used for TL key (column H), team size count (column G), and red name count (column F)
‘LA should be the individual name that is being tested
‘GLA should be an array of each cell from B51:B220 where the value in column H of that same row matches the value of TL

For t = 9 To 35 

TL = Cells(t, 8) 

Set GLA = New Collection

‘add values to GLA here, as a group of all rows in column B where the same rows in column H = TL 
‘I’m guessing that for each value in H51:H220 matching TL, the row number would need to be recorded (as x?)
‘and then added to column 2 to make Cells(x, 2), and then each of these individual cells would be stored in GLA 

For Each LA In GLA 

If LA.Interior.ColorIndex = “22” Then 

p = p + 1 

Else 

p = p 

End If 

‘I’m hoping this will print my p in the appropriate cell but since the code isn’t in running shape yet, i haven’t been able to test it 
Cells(t, 6) = p

Next LA

Next t 

End Sub
```

**edit**
I have discovered collection objects. Now I just need help figuring out how to .Add Cells to it based on value.

Comment: I think you need to set GLA as the range? `Set GLA = Range("A1:A5")` - I'm not quite sure what you're after

Comment: The thing about GLA is that it won’t be contiguous because the names and groups are all mixed up. So GLA would have to be filled by searching through a larger range (H51:H220)

Comment: Sorry if it doesn’t make sense. Like, say I had a bunch of cities in column B, and the country each city belongs to in column H, but the cities are in alphabetical order, so the countries are all mixed up. It wouldn’t be “A1:A5”, more like “A3, A6, A18, A23......” and I don’t know how to make a mixed Range like that

Comment: You made excellent progress with the collection objects! +1. I provided an answer that uses dictionaries (similar to collection, but with some advantages). Also, your last comment provides more useful details and should be part of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data looks similar to this, the code bellow generates the counts in column F

[image: data]

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CountRedCities()
    Const FR_CTR = 9            'First Row - Countries
    Const LR_CTR = 42           'Last Row  - Countries
    Const FR_CITY = 51          'First Row - Cities
    Const CTR_COL = "H"         'Country Column
    Const CNT_COL = "F"         'Count Column
    Const CTY_COL = "B"         'City Column

    Dim ws As Worksheet:        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    Dim ctrCel As Object:       Set ctrCel = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim ctrRed As Object:       Set ctrRed = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim r As Long
    For r = FR_CTR To LR_CTR  'read all countries (9 to 42) in dictionary
        ctrCel(ws.Cells(r, CTR_COL).Value2) = CNT_COL & r   'reference to F cells
    Next
    Dim country As String, red As Long
    red = RGB(255, 128, 128)  'same as .Interior.ColorIndex = 22
    For r = FR_CITY To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, CTY_COL).End(xlUp).Row
        If ws.Cells(r, CTY_COL).Interior.Color = red Then   'check red cities
            country = ws.Cells(r, CTR_COL)
            ctrRed(country) = ctrRed(country) + 1           'increment red country count
        End If
    Next
    Dim itm As Variant
    For Each itm In ctrRed  'plcace count, based on country key, back to the sheet
        If ctrCel.Exists(itm) Then
            ws.Range(ctrCel(itm)).Value2 = ctrRed(itm)
        Else
            MsgBox "Missing Country in rows " & FR_CTR & " to " & LR_CTR & ": " & itm
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

It assumes

- all groups (countries) in range `H9:H35` are unique
- all cities (`B51:B220`) and countries (`H51:H220`) contain only one item in cells
- no cell errors exist generated by formulas in country column
- working sheet name is `"Sheet3"`

---

.

Code works a bit backwards, but it "divides and conquers" one task at the time

- Makes a list of countries in `H9:H35`, and their corresponding **`F`** cells (`F9:F35`)
- The list in the dictionary is based on `country`, as key
- We don't really care about the city - just need to know if it's red or not

  - if red, we do care about its country, so
  - create a new dictionary that keeps track of the count (based also on country)

    - if the country doesn't exist in dictionary yet, add it as a new item
    - else, just increase its count
- at the end, place all counts in corresponding F cells for each country

  - if a country found in `H51:H220` is missing from list `H9:H35`, it identifies it in a MsgBox

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! On the test workbook I put together, it worked great, but when I went to run it in the actual sheet, it filled in 11 of the 27 countries and then gave me a “run-time error ‘1004’: Method ‘Range’ of object ’_Worksheet’ failed. Then it highlighted the line “ws.Range(ctrCel(itm)).Value2 = ctrRed(itm)”

Comment: My worksheet name has a space in it - could that be the problem?

Comment: @Sylphie - I was able to duplicate the issue, and updated the answer to help you fix it. There are countries in range `H51:H220` that are missing from the top list (range `H9:H35`). (The Worksheet name with spaces in it shouldn't cause issues as long as you keep it enclosed in quotation marks - **`"Sheet3"`**)

Comment: You are correct and I’m ridiculously impressed with you for figuring that out from just that error message. My bad!! Thanks for all your help~~~

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) Thanks for the feedback!